# Return object from list for which a specific condition calculated from other objects in list is correct

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
 last_question = max(answer.question_id for answer in answers)
```

I need to retrieve not only the maximum question_id, but also the very `answer` object which contains this `question_id`. I can do it with the next code (assuming `answers` non-empty):

```
max_answer = answers[0]
for answer in answers:
     if answer.question_id > max_answer.question_id:
         max_answer = answer
last_question = max_answer.question_id
```

But can I do it shorter in a Python way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument of [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
max_answer = max(answers, key=lambda q: q.question_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` with [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
import operator

max_answer = max(answers, key=operator.attrgetter("question_id"))
```